# Wait until converse.js joins room

Tags: converse.js

Is there a way through which we can wait until converse.js has joined a room? And once we have joined, we receive some sort of event ? I see that the converse documentation has a tag that can wait until converse.js has fully loaded

```
_converse.on('connected', function () { ... });
```

I was wondering if there is a way to call this API from JS on webapage ?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `chatRoomOpened` event.

More info here: https://conversejs.org/docs/html/events.html#chatroomopened